# How do I make a icon I already have on my website a share button?

Tags: html, css

I have looked all over google and how here how to do it and still haven't found anything. I don't need extra buttons. I need to know how to make a icon I already have on my website a share button. I need to add this function to four icons currently on my site; a facebook, twitter, pinterest, and email icon. You can see the icons on my website http://boasish.com

The html code associated with the icons is as follows:

```
<div class="spyr_sliding_share">
<div class="spyr_sliding_share_text">Share</div>
<div class="spyr_sliding_share_wrap">
        <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_facebook">
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook"><span>Facebook</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_twitter">
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_pinterest">
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-pinterest"><span>Pinterest</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_mail">
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-mail"><span>Email a Friend</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Ignore any part of the html on my actual website that starts with `<div class="spyr_sb_inner">`

Comment: So the problem is where exactly?

Comment: @fstanis I reworded my question. Sorry about that I wasn't clear at all.

Comment: Are you looking at this : http://petragregorova.com/articles/social-share-buttons-with-custom-icons/

Comment: Yes thank you but I need to know how to add the url to the icons currently already on my site.

Answer (score 2):

Add an image to your css / class, Hope this help

For Example:

Starting with your facebook class

```
.spyr_sliding_share_button.spyr_sb_facebook {
    background-image: url('img/my-custom-facebook-icon.png');
}

/* this will remove the 'SPYR-Icons' icon */
.spyr_sliding_share_button.spyr_sb_facebook .icon:before {
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to add a share link to the current icon that is already on the site. I don't need to hide the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for something like this:

http://www.sharethis.com/#sthash.BPfmMwb1.dpbs

It's free and will share to multiple channels if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that's not what I'm looking for. I saw that but I am looking to make my own social media icons a social share button.